# Is it possible to have more than one key in a loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I don't have a problem, but i'm looking for any other maybe better or faster solution.
I have array with two keys ALL and ART:

```
$myData = Array (
 [ALL] => Array (
   [0] => Array (
    [ID_COUNTRY] => 23
    [DELIVERY_DAYS] => 23
    [AMOUNT] => 23
   )
  [1] => Array (
   [ID_COUNTRY] => 30
   [DELIVERY_DAYS] => 30
   [AMOUNT] => 30
  )
 )
 [ART] => Array (
  [0] => Array (
   [ID_COUNTRY] => 10
   [DELIVERY_DAYS] => 10
   [AMOUNT] => 10
  )
  [1] => Array (
   [ID_COUNTRY] => 2
   [DELIVERY_DAYS] => 20
   [AMOUNT] => 20
  )
 )
)
```

And have 2 foreach loops to check the values

```
<?php 
foreach ($myData as $key1=>$key2) {
  foreach ($key2 as $key=>$data) { 
    ...
  }
}
?>
```

Is possible to do something like this or is the only solution to use two foreach loops without any additional libraries.

```
<?php
foreach($myData as $key1=>$key2=>$value) {
 echo $key1; // [ALL] or [ART]
 echo $key2; // [ALL][$key2] or [ART][$key2];
}
?>
```

Comment: make a function to do the task

Comment: I just wanted to create shortcut for foreach, but i now see that this is not possible.

Comment: i voted for "not a real question" as I fail to see *a problem* here. just wasting SO participants time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to loop over your multi-dimensional array you need your provided code:

```
foreach ($myData as $key1=>$key2) {
  foreach ($key2 as $key=>$data) { 
    ...
  }
}
```

No way around it without using something that would in the end do this too. There is no speed to be gained here. And if there is it would be a micro-optimization that you should ignore :)

Comment: I see that this is currently the only solutions as i expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. But you could do it as

```
<?php 
foreach ($myData as $key1=>$key2) {
  foreach ($key2 as $key=>$data) { 
    echo $key1;
    echo $key2;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP says he has?

Comment: @Juhana, I want it to be clear to OP that they can access all keys from within the nested foreach loops

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not exactly what you are looking for; I still wanted to notify you of it though. You *can* recursively loop through a multidimensional array, using a [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) in combination with a [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveArrayIterator( $myData ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
foreach( $rii as $key => $value )
{
    echo $key;

    // you can keep track of the current depth with:
    $depth = $rii->getDepth();
}
```